# PHP WebSocket – How send message to specified client?

Tags: php, websocket

Sending messages to all clients looks like this:

```
function send_message($msg)
{
    global $clients;
    foreach($clients as $changed_socket)
    {
        socket_write($changed_socket, $msg, strlen($msg));
    }
    return true;
}
```

How I can send message to specified client, example to client #2? $clients array looks like this:

```
Array
(
   [0]
   [1]
   [2]
   [3]
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of running a foreach loop to send messages to every client, just send to the one you want.

```
function send_message($msg)
{
    global $clients;
    socket_write($clients[2], $msg, strlen($msg));
    return true;
}
```